# IntelliJ IDEA Reopen Project "The path <insert temp path here> does not exist" error

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

Here's a fun one. I did search for this issue but didn't seem to find anything that helped, including the following questions which seemed most closely related:

[Why am I getting "Local path does not exist" from my Android project in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970583/why-am-i-getting-local-path-does-not-exist-from-my-android-project-in-intellij)

[IntelliJ IDEA: Project SDK Settings is not retained after reopenning IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889987/intellij-idea-project-sdk-settings-is-not-retained-after-reopenning-ide)

**Version info**:
MacBook Pro mid-2014 (Intel), Big Sur 11.2.1

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-212.5284.40, built on September 13, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.2.1

Kotlin: 212-1.5.10-release-IJ5284.40

**Issue description**: On opening an existing project, importing the related module, and selecting the SDK, everything works fine. However, the recent projects list shows what appears to be a random, temporary path to the project IML:

[image: screenshot of error dialog and random project path]

The path you see in the screenshot is not the path that leads to the IML. Not even by a long shot. This is created when opening the project initially but, on exiting IDEA, it seemingly disappears and I have to reimport the project all over again. I am stumped here. I spent a couple of days digging through SO, and the internet in general but can't seem to find anything related to this specific error or anything that has helped at all. Any input would be great. This is on a fresh installation of IDEA, and I have cleared the caches with no observable effect.

Comment: What is the real path of your project? Is it on a local or network drive? Try to close the project and the IDE, open the project root directory in the OS file explorer, delete all.iml files and the .idea directory, and [reimport the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project) from existing sources.

Comment: It's on a local drive. There is no .idea folder in the project directory, even after removing the IML file and reloading *however* deleting the IML and reloading using the source files seems to have worked. If you make this an answer, I'll go ahead and select it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close the project and the IDE, open the project root directory in the OS file explorer, delete all.iml files and the .idea directory, and [reimport the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project) from existing sources

Answer (score 0):

You can try "open" button on the IDE welcome page, I made it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).